# Can an etcd cluster recover like this: (a,b,c) -> (a,b) -> (a) -> (a,c)

Tags: high-availability, etcd

Suppose we have a 3-node etcd cluster with nodes (a, b, c). Node C goes down. The cluster continues operating, let's say many write operations occur during this time. Node B goes down, quorum is no longer possible so the cluster goes down. Node C comes up but is behind node A. Can nodes A and C resume normal cluster operation?